# passing the value using intent from two different activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to pass value from two different activities (Invoice, contact) but onto same activity (AllContacts)..
first activity(Invoice) used intent and get back data from AllContacts i.e. (same for both) activity, here on Item Click if the value come from invoice then it reveres back to invoice with some result other wise go to next activity.
I did something this (ex) but it works only for invoice..

```
    class AllContacts
    invoiceContact=i.getStringExtra("invoiceContact");//from Invoice

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id)
    {


        super.onItemClick(parent, v, position, id);

        Cursor c = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position);
        String keyId = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ID));


        try{
    if(!invoiceContact.toString().equals("")){
               invoiceContact=null;
            Intent extra = new Intent();

         extra.putExtra(RESULT_PATH, keyId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, extra);

            finish();

    }

        else if(invoiceContact.toString().equals("")) { //for Contact intent

        Intent launchContactRowDetails = new Intent(this,
                ContactRowDetails.class);
        launchContactRowDetails.putExtra("KeyId", keyId);
        updateLastFinishedActivity(Constants.ContactRowDetails);
        startActivity(launchContactRowDetails);
        }
    }
        catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Comment: i have not permiss to create new question

Comment: Then read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th. It is still not an excuse to edit your question, to replace it with another, once you have already attracted answers.

Answer (score 0):

In the Intent where you should go to another activity

```
Intent extra = new Intent();
```

You have to specify the activity where u have to go like

```
Intent launchContactRowDetails = new Intent(this, ContactRowDetails.class);
```

Like you have in the lower if loop.

Comment: if(!invoiceContact.toString().equals("")){
               invoiceContact=null;
            Intent extra = new Intent();

         extra.putExtra(RESULT_PATH, keyId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, extra);

            finish();  //it goes from where it called with extra's value

Comment: then I think that invoiceContact is always null once try to Log the value of it,then we will know the reason

Comment: thanq guys i got the problem actually here when i go with invoice it works fine bt when go through contacts it takes value null in invoiceContact because i was not passing the value from contact ... that's the problem so i solved..thanqs alot

Answer (score 0):

You could start the `AllContactsAcitivity` from both the activities with:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

and return the result to whichever activity called it as:

```
Intent result = new Intent("com.example.RESULT_ACTION", Uri.parse("content://result_uri");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
finish();
```

For more information you may read here: [Interaction with other apps](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html) (Don't worry about the title, it can be used within the same application)